# is it possible to add a legend for bubble size in high charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm using the latest version of high charts. I successfully created a 3d bubble chart following http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bubble-3d

I am wondering if I can add to the legend a reference to what the size of the bubble means. Just a simple bubble with some text next to it would be enough.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is best to include a sample of your code, what you have tried so far, so that we can help out with that. Please edit your post and include more information so we can help.

Comment: Looks like you can use the `tooltip` option to create and format the details in the bubble.

Comment: You can use `legend.title`, see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.title).

Answer (score 0):

Just add an empty series and name it.Give it desired name ,See [Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/zajwc06u/)

```
   {
   name :"description",     
   marker: {
            fillColor: {
                radialGradient: { cx: 0.4, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                stops: [
                    [0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]).setOpacity(0.5).get('rgba')]
                ]
            }
        }}
```

Comment: This does not give a legend for the Size of the bubble.  Believe question is how to add a legend for referencing the size of the bubbles.

Answer (score 0):

Representing bubble size in a legend is not currently a feature of Highcharts.

You can draw one manually:

1. Add a series for the legend
2. Draw a rendered box around the legend

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f1hz43bc/3/)

### Add a series for the legend

```
series: [{
      // This series gives a legend for reference
      data: [{
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
        x: 86,
        y: 25,
        z: 10,
        dataLabels: {
          format: '10%',
          y: 40
        }
      }, {
        x: 90,
        y: 25,
        z: 15,
        dataLabels: {
          format: '15%',
          y: 40
        }
      }, {
        x: 94,
        y: 25,
        z: 35,
        dataLabels: {
          format: '35%',
          y: 40
        }
      }]
    }, {
      color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
      data: [{
        x: 95,
        y: 95,
        z: 13.8,
        name: 'BE',
        country: 'Belgium'
      }, {
```

### Draw a rendered box around the legend

```
events: {
  load: function() {

    // Draw the flow chart
    var ren = this.renderer,
      colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;

    // Script label
    ren.label('Obesity Rate', 410, 220)
      .attr({
        stroke: '#777',
        'stroke-width': 1,
        padding: 5,
        r: 5,
        width: 168,
        height: 73
      })
      .css({
        color: '#333',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: '1.1em'
      })
      .add();
  }
}
```